# Racket: tail recursion on list outputs a reversed list

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, racket, tail-recursion

I want my function to square every number in a given list, also, if an
element in lst is a list, the function is applied on it recursively and operates on the elements of that list too.

This is my code:

```
(define (sqr-up-rec-tail lst)
  (define (helper lst newlist)
    (if (null? lst) newlist
      (if (list? (car lst))
          (helper (cdr lst) (cons (sqr-up-rec-tail (car lst)) newlist))
          (helper (cdr lst) (cons (* (car lst) (car lst)) newlist)))))
  (helper lst ()))
```

My function works, however, I get a reversed squared list.
For example, when I run:

> (sqr-up-rec-tail '(2 4 6 (10 20)))

the output I get is:

> ((400 100) 36 16 4)

I want to get the right output **without** using the external reverse function. My guess is that I should use append instead of cons, though I didn't get it to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Simply change `...if (null? lst) newlist...` in `...if (null? lst) (reverse newlist)...`.

Comment: @Renzo "I want to get the right output *without* using the external reverse function."

Answer (score 3):

`append` can work, but remember that makes your function O(n²) time since append is basically this:

```
(define (append a b)
  (if (null? a)
      b
      (cons (car a)
            (append (cdr a) b))))
```

Since `append` is such a bad O(n) time and space. It will make your resulting algorithm O(n²) time and space since you use it for each sublist upto the full list of result.

Since you already have a helper you can just use that to make your own `reverse`:

```
(define (reverse-helper from to)
  (if (null? from)
      to
      (reverse-helper (cdr from) (cons (car from) to))))
```

And in stead of returning the result of `(helper lst '())` you do `(reverse (helper lst '()) '())`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with using tail recursion here is that the first element that gets processed ends up being the last element in newlist, hence the need for procedures like `append` and `reverse`. You can construct the procedure **without** using `append` or `reverse` by avoiding tail recursion, as follows:

```
(define (map-sqr lst)
  (cond
    [(null? lst) empty]
    [(pair? (car lst))
     (cons (map-sqr (car lst))
           (map-sqr (cdr lst)))]
    [else
     (cons (* (car lst) (car lst))
           (map-sqr (cdr lst)))]))
```

But, if you must use tail recursion, then as you noted, `append` can be used while accumulating to get the desired output, as follows:

```
(define (map-sqr-tail lst)
  (let loop ([lst lst]
             [new-lst '()])
    (cond
      [(null? lst) new-lst]
      [(pair? (car lst))
       (loop (cdr lst)
             (append new-lst (list (loop (car lst) empty))))]
      [else
       (loop (cdr lst)
             (append new-lst (list (* (car lst) (car lst)))))])))
```

Both implementations work as expected:

```
> (map-sqr '(2 4 6 (10 20 (30))))
'(4 16 36 (100 400 (900)))
> (map-sqr-tail '(2 4 6 (10 20 (30))))
'(4 16 36 (100 400 (900)))
```